# Unable to update the Cursor of Database when using BaseAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-listview

After going through many tutorials i successfully implemented the database in my android application and everything is working fine except for one thing. My application is built to receive the text message(SMS) and store them in database and also populate them on the ListView. When the application receives the message, the database is updated but the listview is not updated in that instance, but after restaring the app the listview will be populated with all the received data in the database. Please help me sort this problem.
here is my code snippet:
Main class

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import com.example.bhash.database.Adapter;
    import com.example.bhash.database.MessageData;
    import com.example.bhashsms.adapters.DrawerAdapter;
    import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity;

    public class Main extends SlidingActivity {
        ListView dList, mList;
        DrawerAdapter dAdapter;
        static MessageData db;
        static Adapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setBehindContentView(R.layout.drawer);
            init();
            db = new MessageData(Main.this);

            adapter = new Adapter(this);
            mList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        private void init() {
            getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);
            dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
            mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
        }

        public static void update(String number, String body) {
            // adapter.list.add(new Person_Data(number, body));
            try {

                db.open();
                db.createEntry(number, body);
                db.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
```

databasehelper class:

```
    public class MessageData {

        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_NUMBER = "phone_number";
        public static final String KEY_MESSGAE = "message";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Message";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "SMS";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private Helper helper;
        private Context ourContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

        public MessageData(Context c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            ourContext = c;

        }

        private static class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public Helper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NUMBER
                            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MESSGAE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
                    onCreate(db);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        public MessageData open() {
            helper = new Helper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close() {
            helper.close();
        }

        public long createEntry(String number, String message) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
            cv.put(KEY_MESSGAE, message);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        }

        public List<Person_Data> getData() {
            String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NUMBER, KEY_MESSGAE };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                    null, null);

            // int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iNumber = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER);
            int iMessage = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSGAE);
            Log.i("coaunt value",c.getCount()+"");
            List<Person_Data> list = new ArrayList<Person_Data>();
            c.moveToFirst();

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

                list.add(new Person_Data(c.getString(iNumber), c
                        .getString(iMessage)));

            }
            c.close();
            return list;

        }

    }
```

Adapterclass:

```
    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context c;
        LayoutInflater inflaterr;
        public List<Person_Data> list = new ArrayList<Person_Data>();


        public Adapter(Context c) {
            this.c = c;
            MessageData md = new MessageData(c.getApplicationContext());
            md.open();
            Person_Data datatData;
            list = md.getData();
            Log.i("dasdasdad", list.size()+"");
            md.close();
            inflaterr = LayoutInflater.from(this.c);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            View singleview = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {

                singleview = inflaterr.inflate(R.layout.main_list_view, parent,
                        false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(singleview);
                singleview.setTag(holder);
            }

            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) singleview.getTag();

            }
            final Person_Data data = list.get(position);
            holder.Number.setText(data.Number);
            holder.callme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ExtractNumber(data.Message);

                }

                private void ExtractNumber(String src) {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int j = src.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                        char c = src.charAt(i);
                        if (c == '+') {
                            builder.append(c);
                            for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
                                char r = src.charAt(k);
                                if (!Character.isDigit(r)) {
                                    i = k;
                                    break;
                                }
                                builder.append(r);
                            }
                            if (builder.toString().length() > 8
                                    && builder.toString().length() < 14)
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + builder.toString()));
                    c.startActivity(callIntent);
                }

            });
            return singleview;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView Number, time;
            ImageView callme;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                Number = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rNum);
                callme = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.callbutton);

            }
        }
    }
```